# With harmony how to implement printf to uart?

Tags: pic, microchip, mplab, mplab-harmony

I setup a project using harmony v2 for a pic32mx470f512l. In drivers -> USART i configured the UART (strange its called USART in harmony in datasheet says its a UART):

[image]

Now i want to use the function printf, like we can easily use in MCC.
How can it be implement in harmony?

I seem to have made it work after

but i get wrong chars on termite:
[image]
[image]

The configs i made in device configuration:
[image]

Comment: By default, MPLAB® XC32's libraries use UART2 for STDOUT. This means that formatted output functions such as printf() use UART2.

The MPLAB XC32 compiler provides a __XC_UART variable that you may use to switch the default to UART 1.

Comment: @Mike hi. Yes i used __XC_UART = 1 in my code to use UART1. But the characters are the ones you see on the screenshot. With MCC i had the same problem its really hard to find a frequency of the oscillator and baud rate of UART that works well.

Comment: 9600 baud is really slow, so should be fine. Double check oszillator frequency.

Comment: @Mike after i programmed again the pic it seems its ok now! If this works there is no need for me to use the overcomplicated api debug_uart that harmony has. I hope it is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar issue with a PIC32MX and my solution was to use the configuration as in the image below for the USART driver.

[image: USART settings on Harmony]

Then, I've enabled the 'Use Console System Service?', under 'Harmony Framework Configuration > System Services > Console', using the configurations listed in the image below.

[image: Console settings]

Hopefully, these configurations may be applicable to your situation. Don't forget to configure the desired pins as U2TX and U2RX.

Answer (score -1):

You would not use printf to just send data through the USART. You should use the interface defined by Harmony ([Page 1295](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Driver%20Libraries%20Help%20v2.06.pdf)). If you are looking to send something akin to debug messages, there is a debugger console that is supported that uses the SYS_MESSAGE() function which might be similar enough. There is an example harmony project that demonstrates how to use it (located at microchip\harmony\v2_05\apps\examples\system\debug_uart\firmware\src)

Comment: The thing is i'm porting a project from a pic16f that uses printf for uart. It is not possible to use it with USART in pic32? I will check that example, it works the same way as printf then?

Comment: It works the same way as printf() at a high level. You can familiarize yourself with the console interface in this application note:
http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/System%20Service%20Libraries%20Help%20v2.06.pdf